# How to check if a view already added to a region in PRISM?

Tags: wpf, prism

I have a region and want to check whether a specific view type is added to it or not. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

The following code (using Linq) should be useful:

```
regionManager.Regions["RegionName"].Views.Any(v => v.GetType() == typeof(ViewType));
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 2):

You can check to see if a view has been added to a region using the following method.

```
var regionManager = Get reference to the region manager
bool viewHasBeenAdded = regionManager.Regions["Your region"].GetView("View Name") != null;
```

Is this what you want or are you actualy wanting to check for Type rather than View name?

Answer (score 0):

```
object obj = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(cntrlName);

var checkIfAlreadyExists = 
RegionManager.Regions["ApplicationCoreRegion"].Views.Contains(obj);

if (checkIfAlreadyExists) {
    MessageBox.Show("Can not add this, because it is already shown");
} else {
    RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ApplicationCoreRegion", () => obj);
    RegionManager.Regions["ApplicationCoreRegion"].Activate(obj);
}
```